# Handle Scroll events in WM5 CListView

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, windows-mobile-5.0

In my WinModile 5 app I'm using CListView with report style to display a table of items. Since there can be significant amount of items(> 1000) it takes a lot of time to insert them all. But most of the time users only need first 50 or so. I would like to insert items dynamically when they are needed. To do this a need to catch the vertical scrolling to add items. I can't find a way to do this with our sub-classing the CListCtrl as well as CListView.

So the question is is there another way to implement on-demand rendering or to catch scroll events without sub-classing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you heard of [Virtual ListViews](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158643.aspx)?  Virtual ListViews are typically used when you have performance problems with a listview containing a large amount of data.  The application is responsible for managing the data to be displayed in the Virtual ListView.  Windows will ask for the data only when it needs to display the data.  A sample project named VirtualListView is included with the Windows Mobile SDK.